# Ajax implementation using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml

I want to implement a simple AJAX script which tries to display data stored in a xml file. I tried this following code but on press of the button the page seems static and nothing responds back. The script doesn't display the xml contents.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>XML</title>
  <script>
    function myfun() {
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.req");
      }
      req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (req.readyState === 4 && req.status === 200) {
          document.getElementById("myid").innerHTML = req.responseText;
        }
      }
      //req.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
      req.open("GET", "myxml.xml", true);
      req.send();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myid">This will change</div>
  <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfun()" />
</body>
</html>
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<student>
  <id>100</id>
  <name>tamizh</name>
</student>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?  Have you checked your browser's dev tool's "network" tab to see if anything is happening?

Comment: May be you can try logging somthing in the error handler?

Comment: This is the error i got at the console-

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Rakesh/Desktop/New%20folder%20(3)/myxml.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.myfun @ ajax.html:23

Comment: You can only use AJAX if your page is on a *webserver*.  You can run a local webserver (such as WampServer or XAMPP), but you cannot use AJAX just from a file (using `file:///`).

Comment: Although I guess firefox allows AJAX with local files without server?

Comment: @SandeepNayak: Chome does too, but you need to set a special flag.

Comment: Yeah I just checked that and thank you guys so much. But why is this question downvoted, I just add a doubt regarding my subject.Damn this forum is harsh..

Comment: I did not downvote you. Perhaps, someone dv because you didn't provide an error message in the origin post. And this is a multiple answered question on SO; a duplicate. Let me upvote your question and say welcome on SO. ;-)